# Javascript within a php include. GetElementByID looks for div in parent document not the included document

Tags: php, javascript, getelementbyid

I have a PHP file that has a section of the page while the rest uses an include to show the rest of the page. In the included php document I have some javascript that uses getElementById to find the width of a div however the javascript seems to search for the div in the parent document. I have included an image to demonstrate the problem.

[Example Image here](http://imgur.com/wN0aD4n)

Is there any way to get the javascript to locate the div inside the included document and not the parent document?

**Edit: I am not sure how but it has just started working. Must have just had a bit of syntax missing. Any chance a moderator could delete this for me please?**

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server. `include` adds a chunk of code from another file at the point where it is called. The output of the PHP is sent to the browser as a *single* document.

The browser does not (and cannot) know or care about the include. It only sees a single document with two elements that share an id. This is not allowed in HTML and it attempts to recover from the error.

Fix your code so it doesn't generate a document with duplicate IDs. Check the generated HTML with [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: The example div inside the parent document is just to show that the getelement retrieves the value from there and not the included document, and if the div is not present in the parent document the value returns null.

Comment: @CoreyD97 — You should reread the second paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you including the file so on your page you have to div's with same id i.e

```
<div id="example">
   width="150px"
</div>

<div id="example">
   width="15px"
</div>
```

Now getElementById will give you the value of 1st as both are having same id,

try using different id's. this will work.